# Javascript if statement doesn't output the value I want when the element is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I can't seem to find what i'm doing wrong here. I want to have it so that if there is no value of metar.ceiling.feet (which is taken from an API) it just outputs "Clear skies" as text. I can't get it to do this though as when I try it and metar.ceiling.feet has no value, the "Clear skies" text does not show. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. My html code is below as well in case that is neccessary.

```
      if (metar.ceiling) {
        document.getElementById('ceiling_block').classList.remove("d-none");
        var x = document.createElement('p');
        if (metar.ceiling.feet === "") {
              x.innerText = "Clear skies";
            } else {   
              x.innerText = metar.ceiling.feet + 'ft';
            }
            document.getElementById("ceiling_feet").append(x);
      }
```

```
        <div id="ceiling_block" class="infocard">
        <h5 class="titleslive">Lowest Cloud</h5><h5 class="infolive"><span id="ceiling_feet"></span></h5>
        </div>
```

Comment: `console.log(metar.ceiling.feet)` is it really an empty string?

Comment: It must be empty as if it wasn't it would have outputted the value, right?

Comment: Is it empty or undefined?

Comment: Well there's no value so empty.

Comment: `console.log(typeof metar.ceiling.feet);`

Comment: Add a debugger statement, walk though the code and see what happens. Inspect the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add checks for undefined condition also

```
if (!!metar.ceiling) {
        document.getElementById('ceiling_block').classList.remove("d-none");
        var x = document.createElement('p');
        if (!metar.ceiling.feet || metar.ceiling.feet === "") {
              x.innerText = "Clear skies";
        } else {   
              x.innerText = metar.ceiling.feet + 'ft';
         }
        document.getElementById("ceiling_feet").append(x);
}
```

Comment: The additional checking you added is not only for undefined. It checks all falsy values which include null, false, 0 and empty string. In this case the second part of the checking is never reached. You can either remove the second part or add an explicit comparison to `undefined` in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if (typeof parseInt(metar.ceiling.feet) !== 'number') {
              x.innerText = "Clear skies";
            } else {   
              x.innerText = metar.ceiling.feet + 'ft';
 }
```